# How to extract a field from internal hits in elastic search watcher payload

Tags: elasticsearch, mustache, elasticsearch-watcher

scenario: I have setup a watch in elastic search which is returning 10(assume) hits.

Now i have to extract a particular field from every hits. If i will write this {{ctx.payload.hits.hits.0._source.message}} in watcher code then it will only return message of first index. Manualy I am able to get messages of every hits(10). How to iterate over all hits in elastic search watcher to get message field of every hits. How could i correlate it with number of hits (here like hits are 10).

Please share your valuable response. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I would look at moving the logic into a separate transform groovy file which you save in config/scripts/transform.groovy and in there you would have no problem writing the iteration logic you need.

Comment: An example of this file and the watcher link to it would be nice